# i am facing Firebase Notification Error in react native with node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
Successfully sent message: {
  results: [ { error: [FirebaseMessagingError] } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 1,
  successCount: 0,
  multicastId: 3557995281676880400
}
```

This Is the error log i am getting
Whats the issue ?

Comment: Use a Proper Firebase token

Comment: i am passing token properly